# After Effects - Element 3D: Text arranged in a circle/ring form

Tags: after-effects, 3d

I need to dispose some letters extruded with Element 3D plug-in in After Effects
Like in this fast example:

[image]

I'm going crazy! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make some text
2. Draw a circle mask within it and set mode to 'none'
3. Go text's Path option and select mask You've created
4. Adjust mask or/and font to get desirable result

Continue to work with Element 3D as in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0p9gwKMSqk